# MobilePush Contacts Registered As "Opted Out"

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, mobile, mobilepush

We are trying to opt in contacts to MobilePush in order to send them push notifications. Usually it works pretty well, but now contacts who register in our app are being inserted as contacts who "Opted Out" instead of "Opted In". It looks like this (Open the photo for a better resolution):

[image]

What can cause that sort of a problem?

Comment: It's most likely following the SDK parameters when it comes to device notification settings.  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_mp_opt_outs.htm&type=5
If an app is downloaded and they don't allow notifications, they're opted out.

Comment: We've tested the app using our devices, and obviously enabled push notifications, and still, same result as above.

Comment: You should validate which cert you're using/sending to.  Most often the wrong certificate is being used and that will result in the contact being opted-out based on the responses from APNS' Feedback Service.

Comment: Problem Solved. Forgot to set the senderID. Anyway thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved. Forgot to set the senderID. Anyway thank you all for your help!